# Link jQuery datepicker and FullCalendar across pages

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, fullcalendar, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a ui datepicker set up on the homepage of my site and a separate events page that contains my FullCalendar that is full of events. My question: is it possible to click on a datepicker day and for it to link you to the events page and bring up the selected day view on FullCalendar?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it's possible.

Use the `change()` function of the `<input>` that hosts the datepicker to read the selected value and navigate to the target page with the date as a query string parameter.

#### Edit

If the datepicker is not bound to an `<input>` the `onSelect` event can be used.

```
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
      window.location = "http://example.com/events?date=" + dateText;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm not using an input field though. It's just a div with an id of "datepicker". I'm using it as a mini-calendar, not as a date selector for a form.

Comment: Ok, I don't know if I understand correctly what you want, but I made another try in an edit to the answer.

Comment: Okay, that is working in that it's taking me to the calendar page and showing the date in the query string. Now, do I need to grab that value with php in order to switch the FullCalendar view to the day you clicked? Thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: Greabbing the value with php is another step - if yo uneed help with that you should post another question. If this was helpful, you should mark my answer as accepted by clicking the check mark.